$E[X\mid \max(X,Y,Z)]$ with dependent variables
Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be a three-dimensional random variable with density function $f(x,y,z)=\frac{2}{3}(x+y+z)$ on $0<x,y,z<1$. Calculate $E[X\mid \max(X,Y,Z)]$.
I think the answer is $\frac{25}{36}\max(X, Y, Z)$, but I'm not sure:

How did you evaluate the purported answer? Please show your attempts. This would propel helpful answers.

Simulation suggests $\frac{25}{36}\max(X,Y,Z)$ is not implausible.

Hi, Speltzu, I noticed that you have posted many interesting and profound problems (unlike others, I do not consider your questions are trivial textbook self-study questions) on conditional expectations.  Miraculously, with very few or non-standard arguments, almost every time your final answer is correct.  Could you share with us where did you find these conditional expectation problems or are they created by yourself? I think it would help other users in this forum who want to bring their understanding of conditional expectation to the next level a lot.

For this question, I have prepared a proof that confirms your guess is indeed correct.  If you added more details to this question, then we can reopen it and I would undelete my answer to share it with you.

@User1865345 Once the question gets reopened, I will certainly undelete my answer.  It is a concise, neat and delicious problem that is worth trying!

Denote $\max(X, Y, Z)$ by $M$. In analogous to the well-known identity $E[X] = \int_0^\infty P[X > x]dx$ for a non-negative random variable $X$, we will use the identity
\begin{align*}
E[X|M = m] = \int_0^m P[X> x|M = m]dx \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{align*}
to determine the conditional expectation in the OP. So the central task is to evaluate the conditional probability $P[X > x | M = m]$ for $0 < x < m < 1$.
By the result of Problem 33.16 in Probability and Measure by Patrick Billingsley:
\begin{align*}
P[X > x | M = m] &= \lim_{h \downarrow 0} P[X > x | m - h < M \leq m + h] \\
&= \lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{P[X > x, m - h < M \leq m + h]}{P(m - h < M \leq m + h)}. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
Since the density of $M = \max(X, Y, Z)$ is $f(t) = 4t^3I_{(0, 1)}(t)$, it is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
& P(m - h < M \leq m + h) = \int_{m - h}^{m + h}4t^3 dt \\
=& (m + h)^4 - (m - h)^4 = 8mh(m^2 + h^2). \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
On the other hand, given that $0 < x < m < 1$, for sufficiently small $h$, we have $x < m - h$, it then follows that
\begin{align*}
 & P[X > x, m - h < M \leq m + h] \\
=& P[X > x, M \leq m + h] - P[X > x, M \leq m - h] \\
=& P[X > x, X \leq m + h, Y \leq m + h, Z \leq m + h] \\ 
 & - P[X > x, X \leq m - h, Y \leq m - h, Z \leq m - h] \\
=& P[x < X \leq m + h, Y \leq m + h, Z \leq m + h] \\
 & - P[x < X \leq m - h, Y \leq m - h, Z \leq m - h] \\
=& \int_x^{m + h}\int_0^{m + h}\int_0^{m + h}\frac{2}{3}(u + v + w)dudvdw \\ 
&- \int_x^{m - h}\int_0^{m - h}\int_0^{m - h}\frac{2}{3}(u + v + w)dudvdw  
\\
=& \int_x^{m + h}\int_0^{m + h}\int_0^{m + h}\frac{2}{3}(u + v + w)dudvdw \\ 
&- \int_x^{m - h}\int_0^{m - h}\int_0^{m - h}\frac{2}{3}(u + v + w)dudvdw  
\\
=& \frac{1}{3}(m + h)^2(m + h - x)(m + h + x) + 
\frac{2}{3}(m + h)^3(m + h  - x) \\ 
&- \frac{1}{3}(m - h)^2(m - h - x)(m - h + x) -
\frac{2}{3}(m - h)^3(m - h  - x)  \\
=& \frac{1}{3}(m + h)^2(m + h - x)(3m + 3h + x) \\
&- \frac{1}{3}(m - h)^2(m - h - x)(3m - 3h + x) \\
=& \frac{4}{3}m(m - x)(3m + x)h + \frac{2}{3}m^2(3m + x)h + 
2m^2(m - x)h + o(h). \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align*}
Combining $\eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, \eqref{3}$ then gives
\begin{align*}
 & P[X > x | M = m] \\
=& \frac{1}{6m^2}(m - x)(3m + x) + \frac{1}{12m}(3m + x) + \frac{1}{4m}(m - x) \\
=& 1 - \frac{x}{2m} - \frac{x^2}{6m^2}. \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align*}
Substituting $\eqref{4}$ into $\eqref{0}$ then yields
\begin{align*}
E[X|M = m] &= \int_0^m\left(1 - \frac{x}{2m} - \frac{x^2}{6m^2}\right)dx \\
&= m - \frac{1}{2m}\frac{1}{2}m^2 - \frac{1}{6m^2}\frac{1}{3}m^3 \\
&= m - \frac{1}{4}m - \frac{1}{18}m \\
&= \frac{25}{36}m,
\end{align*}
i.e., $E[X|M] = \frac{25}{36}M$, which matches the proposed answer.

Great @Zhanxiong, good to know other approaches.

@Speltzu Can you tell us where does this exercise come from?

I make them up.

@Speltzu Impressive :)

You should make a collection and write a blog @Speltzu (and for God's sake, learn the common terminologies). Zhanxiong, nothing to say, nice answer, as usual.
